# Difference between active time and actual time it was active.

Tags: support, timestamps, timeline

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/763188/optimization-of-the-surface-area-of-a-open-rectangular-box-to-find-the-cost-of-m) question was protected at February 25, 06:27:54, but the active time (i.e. the time that you see when you hover over the date shown next to active, below the views), says that the question was last active at February 25, 05:48:10. [The timeline](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/763188/timeline) of the question shows that there were no other events. There are also no deleted answers.

What caused this difference?

Comment: I guess the last activity was a Community♦ bump. Protecting a question is not "activity" in the sense relevant for the "active" link, only things that bump, I think.

Comment: @DanielFischer I verfied it actually was, by going back in the active tab. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last activity was a Community♦ bump at 05:48:10, which was not displayed in the timeline.

Protecting a question does not count for the time displayed at the active timer.